# Maximizing determinant of a specific matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, determinant

Suppose we have a square matrix $A$ of order $n$. Every element is -1, 0 or 1. What is the maximum value of the determinant in this case? Any progress is welcome (e.g. results for specific values of $n\ge 4$, it can help generalize later)

EDIT: Seems like the value is divisible by $2^n$ but I can't quite prove it yet.

Comment: Related: [A034918](http://oeis.org/A034918): "Maximal determinant of $n \times n$ persymmetric matrix with entries $\{-1,0,+1\}$",

$[1, 1, 4, 16, 48, 128, 576, 2560, 12288, 55296, 327680, 2097152]$.

Comment: Also [A215897](http://oeis.org/A215897).

Comment: According to mathworld's entry on [Hadamard's Maximum Determinant Problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html). 
The largest possible determinant among all $n \times n$ $(+1,0,-1)$ matrices equals to the largest possible determinant among all $n \times n$ $(+1,-1)$ matrices ([OEIS A003433](http://oeis.org/A003433) : $1,2,4,16,48,160,576,\ldots$)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with your initial guess. Show that your assumption is true for a $2\times 2$ matrix and for a $3\times 3$ matrix. Note that the upper bound will imply the negative bound by multiplication (you will need this for the Laplace expansion). Then use induction + Laplace expansion to show that you can generalize the result to arbitrary matrices.